# Word for "extremified"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried to describe something I read on the phenomenon that views in groups invariably shift toward the more extreme of the individuals and their group average, so to speak. Therefore there views were [extremified].

Comment: Poles apart. Could you say, the views polarised; or were polarised? US spelling: polarized, were polarized.

Comment: "Radicalized" is a term often used to describe extremists.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, Hugh suggested the word *polarize,* and Hot Licks suggested the word *radicalize*. I agree with you that both suggestions apply to the situation that you describe in the question. These words are often used together.

They have somewhat different meanings. *Polarization* implies the development of opposing extremes (for example, someone might lament the "polarization of politics" in the context of the two-party system of the USA) and the reduction or elimination of intermediate positions between these extremes. *Radicalization" refers to a shift away from mainstream or moderate viewpoints.

Comment: Is it against the rules to ask for an upvote? This SE site seems ... a bit tight! But great answer, thanks